# How to prevent <details/> to expand/collapse when clicking element inside <summary/>?

Tags: html, css

In HTML you have the `<details/>` element which allows you to expand/collapse content inside of it, while the `<summary/>` tag always remains visible. When you click the `<summary/>` element (or one of it's children) it expands/collapses the content. Inside of the `<summary/>` element I have multiple other elements, but not all of them should trigger expand/collapse. I've already tried it with `pointer-events: none` but without success:

```css
.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
}

.not-clickable {
  pointer-events: none;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    <span class="clickable">Clickable</span>
    <span class="not-clickable">Not Clickable</span>
  </summary>
  Some Content
</details>
```

Is it possible to prevent one element inside of `<summary/>` from expanding/collapsing the content of `<details/>`?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve it by setting `pointer-events: none` on `summary` and set it again on `clickable` class.

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach, but it works.

```css
summary {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.clickable {
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
}

.not-clickable{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    <span class="clickable">Clickable</span>
    <span class="not-clickable"><a>Not Clickable</a></span>
  </summary>
  Some Content
</details>
```

Comment: there is just one issue with that solution: the arrow is not clickable anymore